# How to share assertion methods in BDD-style Cocoa unit tests?

Tags: ios, cocoa, unit-testing, bdd

In experimenting with BDD-style unit tests, I ran against a wall that made me back out of the whole thing: the basic examples everyone uses don't include a way to share a common assert method between multiple unit tests.

Frequently, you may need to set up a set of conditions, and then perform several parameterized assertions on them. But block-style BDD doesn't allow you to add this, like you could in a vanilla SenTestCase. Basic example, using Specta, although this could apply to any of them:

```
// PossiblePlace 1

SpecBegin(ClassUnderTest)

    describe(@"ClassUnderTest", ^{
        __block ClassUnderTest* _target;

        beforeEach(^{
            _target = [[ClassUnderTest alloc] init];
        });

        // PossiblePlace 2

        it(@"does thing 1 under some circumstances", ^{
            // Lots of assertions
        });

        it(@"does thing 1 under some other circumstances", ^{
            // Lots of assertions again
        });

        afterEach(^{
            [_target release];
        });
    });

SpecEnd
```

Let's say you have 10 assertions. I don't want to dupe those in each test. That way, each test is nice and readable with just the stuff that's *different* between each test case. Normally it'd be something like this:

```
- (void)assert_LotsOfStuff:(BOOL)expectedResult
{
    BOOL result = [_target someOp];
    STAssertEquals(result, expectedResult, nil);
    // Etc.
}
```

But here you can't do it. If you try to put `assert_LotsOfStuff` into PossiblePlace 1, assertions don't work because it's static, and not in a class. So you don't get `self`, which all STAsserts need. If you try to put it into PossiblePlace 2, you can't because it's not a block.

The only possibility I finally came up with is doing a category on `SPTSenTestCase`, but then you have to pass in every single parameter. I.e., you can't use _target or any mocks because you're not in the context of your test class. If 4 things differ between each test, 4 params is already enough to grok, without passing in every single thing that has setters for those 4 things.

Hopefully I explained the issue and made the case for why it's needed. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specta supports shared examples, these can be used for sharing expectations across multiple classes. Example in this question: [When to use specta's 'sharedExamplesFor'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500343/when-to-use-spectas-sharedexamplesfor)

Comment: That seems like exactly what I was looking for. Will have to try that next time I'm on that project.